# In Java, when the input is something like “a= -5, b= 6, c= 9”, whats the best way to assign those numbers to variables as doubles?

Tags: java, parsing

I've already tried using

```
double a = scnr.nextDouble();
double b = scnr.nextDouble();
double c = scnr.nextDouble();
```

which works when the input is just "-5 6 9", but not when the input has commas and letters. When I try with the input I'm supposed to use I get this error:
Exception in thread "main"

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Do you *need* for the input to contain those things? The simplest solution, when possible, is to simplify your input specification. On the other hand, if you are making use of some established, documented format (for example, .INI), you should use a library specific to that format.

Comment: What is some other example input?

Comment: Not an answer, but in similar situations, what I do is to print / pop up an error message, and tell the user: "Incorrect input. Correct format should be ...". Fast fail with ultra clear error messages

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scanner's [`hasNextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble()) to determine if the next input can be interpreted as a double or not and assign it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map`:

```java
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
scnr.useDelimiter("\n"); // read by lines, not by words
String input = scnr.next();
String[] statements = input.split(",");
for (String statement : statements) {
  String[] args = statement.split("=");
  String key = args[0].trim(); // .trim() removes leading and trailing spaces
  double value = Double.parseDouble(args[1].trim());
  map.put(key, value);
}
```

Read the entire line, split it by commas, split each statement by `=`, remove whitespaces, save statement to map. Once that's done, you can get any values you want:

```
double a = map.get("a");
double b = map.get("b");
double c = map.get("c");
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers you can use `hasNextDouble`, here is an alternative solution using a try/catch:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
        char[] doubleVariableNames = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

        for (char variableName : doubleVariableNames) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.printf("Enter a double value for variable '%s': ", variableName);
                try {
                    double v = sc.nextDouble();
                    if (variableName == 'a') {
                        a = v;
                    } else if (variableName == 'b') {
                        b = v;
                    } else {
                        c = v;
                    }
                    break;
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.err.println("ERROR: Enter a double value.");
                    sc.next();
                }
            }
        }
        
        sc.close();
        System.out.printf("a=%.2f, b=%.2f, c=%.2f\n", a, b, c);
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter a double value for variable 'a': zxc
ERROR: Enter a double value.
Enter a double value for variable 'a': 4.3
Enter a double value for variable 'b': 5.5.5
ERROR: Enter a double value.
Enter a double value for variable 'b': 5.5
Enter a double value for variable 'c': 9
a=4.30, b=5.50, c=9.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the input using a regular expression:

```java
String expr = "a= -5, b= 6.2e2, c= 9E-3";

String assignRegex = " *= *(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?i:e-?\\d+)?) *";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(" *a" + assignRegex +
                           ", *b" + assignRegex +
                           ", *c" + assignRegex).matcher(expr);
if (! m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Invalid expression");
} else {
    double a = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
    double b = Double.parseDouble(m.group(2));
    double c = Double.parseDouble(m.group(3));
    System.out.println("(a, b, c) = (" + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ")");
}
```

*Output*

```
(a, b, c) = (-5.0, 620.0, 0.009)
```